# Keep getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript

error appears after first character is typed in the input
this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").autocomplete({ 
      source: ["c++","asp"]
    });
  });
</script>


<p>
Select from the list below
</p>
<INPUT id="a" />
```

this is the error trace in the chrome developer console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:550
jQuery.extend.parseJSON jquery.js:550
Autocomplete.defaults.transformResult
```

jquery.autocomplete.js;jsessionid=59B4A34FBCA69900E2D9294F569FB4AB:84
    Autocomplete.processResponse jquery.autocomplete.js;jsessionid=59B4A34FBCA69900E2D9294F569FB4AB:643
    (anonymous function) jquery.autocomplete.js;jsessionid=59B4A34FBCA69900E2D9294F569FB4AB:509
    fire jquery.js:3048
    self.fireWith jquery.js:3160
    done jquery.js:8235
    callback jquery.js:8778

Comment: Everything appears to be in order with the code you provided above. We'll need to know which line is reportedly causing the problem.

Comment: updated with the stack trace

Comment: Are you *sure* autocomplete is a function?

Comment: its part of jquery.autocomplete.js which has been added to the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chance are the autocomplete plugin is attempting to make an AJAX request to a page that it expects to be JSON.  That page is returning HTML (probably a 404 or 500) and that HTML is getting parsed as JSON, and failing because the first character is probably the `<` of `<!DOCTYPE>`.

Comment: seems like thats it how would you suggest preventing that from happening? ie to only read in the inputed text.

Comment: I just glanced at the doc page for that plugin and it looks like you're doing it correct.  In the network tab of the dev console, does the URL that this is requesting give you any hints?  Is there some stupid type conversion thing happening where `["a", "b"]` is getting converted to `"a, b"`?  The only thing I could think of would be to help you debug it, you could try changing `source` to a function that returns your array and see if it "takes" that.

Comment: ill give it a try, just looking at it on entering "a" the following is sent Request URL:http://localhost:8080/test?query=a
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source -- You should be able to do what you're trying to do.  Is there code elsewhere that calls `autocomplete` again and sets different values?

Comment: no thats it dumbed it down as much as possible to isolate the problem, just looking up from a a script on the same page, thats the only input on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused too by the omission of the content type, as the following form: 
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"